# Entity Framework not able to retrieve record

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I have some simple code with entity framework..

```
var test = repo.Locales.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LocalePK == 1);

if(test == null)
    throw new Exception($"Repo is not working - connection in itops");

quote = repo.Quotes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuoteRef == quoteReference);

if(quote == null)
{
    throw new Exception($"quote is null??! {quoteReference} length{quoteReference.Length} {test.Territory}");
}
```

And I get an exception with this

quote is null??! WU00553348 length10 United Kingdom of Great Britain & Northern Ireland, the Isle of Man & the Channel Isles: line:71 This has failed 13 times

So it has no issues getting the locale from the DB, but it cant get the quote? the quote is definitely there as I did a select in SQL Server Management Studio...

I have no idea why Entity Framework is having issues here... it works elsewhere in the system... :( Why would it be unable to get a record from quotes table but fine with locales.

Comment: You should probably do some research on what makes two objects equal to each other. The first query searches by primary key, which is a numeric value.

Comment: What version of EF are you using?, in case if EF 6.X, please show your `Local` entity

Comment: The problem here is that EF is not finding a entity Quote in `Quotes` for which `(x.QuoteRef == quoteReference)`. As mentioned by @lucrativelucas, this might be because the object reference `quoteReference` might not be equal to `x.QuoteRef`. Please refer to <https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/02/01/equality-in-net.aspx> for more details on object references and equality in c#

Comment: this works fine in a test environment but this is what happens in a release environment. I have noticed that itops project (where this code is running) has a slightly different version of EF to the project that hosts the entities.. so updating them all to 6.2.0

Comment: Trying to get the quote by id gives the same problem

Comment: Works fine in test and error happens in production?  Have you got expected data in database - generated queries are identical in test and production?  Both test and production SQL Server are setup identical - same collations for string handling etc?

Comment: Indeed, check your DB collation for the infamous (and quite complicated) problem of string comparisons !

Comment: check the whole table, there could be a null value in the quote field, throughout all the records in the table, EF can be a bit sensitive about that if you've configured the field to be non-nullable in your code.

Comment: its fine, turns out it was looking in the wrong database

Comment: @LukeP You have made my day :)